# sed - Replacing brackets with characters?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string that with brackets that enclose a single character, like such:

```
[a]
```

I want to take the character within the bracket and replace the bracket with the character, so the end result would look like:

```
aaa
```

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't work:

```
sed 's/\[ \([a-z]\) \]/\2/g' < testfile
```

Can someone please help me, and explain why my command isn't working?

Comment: What are the spaces in the pattern for? Which capture (from the pattern) is `\2` supposed to be? You are replacing five characters with one character. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Drop the spaces and triple the `\1`, ie: `sed 's/\[\([a-z]\)\]/\1\1\1/g'`

Comment: `sed -e 's/\[\(.\)\]/\1\1\1/g'`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$ echo "[a]" | sed 's/\[\([a-zA-Z]\)\]/\1\1\1/g'
```

or

```
$ echo "[a]" | sed -r 's/\[([a-zA-Z])\]/\1\1\1/g'
```

**Output:**

```
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some basic concepts.  First let's duplicate a single char

```
$ echo a | sed -r 's/(.)/\1\1/' 
aa
```

parenthesis indicates the groups and `\1` refers to the first group

Now, to match a char in square brackets and triple it.

```
$ echo [a]b | sed -r 's/\[(.)\]/\1\1\1/'
aaab
```

you need to escape square bracket chars since they have special meaning in regex.  The key is you have to bracket in parenthesis the regex you're interested in and refer to them in the same order with `\{number}` notation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your patern `sed 's/\[ \([a-z]\) \]/\2/g' < testfile`:

```
1) The pattern has only one group \([a-z]\), so \2 is invalid;
2) The pattern contains space, there is no match found;
3) To replace brackets, you need to capture them in a group.
```

My idea is, to catch all groups in a pattern, and replace them with `\2\2\2`:

```
echo "[a]" | sed 's/\(\[\)\([a-z]\)\(\]\)/\2\2\2/g'
```

Or

```
echo "[a]" | sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\2\2\2/g'
```

The output is:

```
aaa
```